# How can I add mpl_toolkits.mplot3d to matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a 3d figures using matplotlib. The examples I found start with:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
```

But mpl_toolkits.mplot3d is unresolved reference.

Comment: An "unresolved reference", or an `ImportError`?

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using? And how did you install matplotlib?

Comment: @Evert I am getting a zigzag red line under mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.

Comment: @Evert I used "matplotlib-1.4.2.win32-py2.7.exe" to install matplotlib.

Comment: A "zigzag red line" doesn't mean anything to me; you are not using the normal Python prompt, or a script, but some IDE I guess. So you're *not* getting an ImportError then? Because then something else is amiss. Try actually running the code, to see what error it throws.